# Having trouble finding LTSpice (or just spice) models

Tags: diodes, ltspice, spice, model

While looking to run some simulations on LTSpice (or others spice solutions) I cannot seem to find a single source of truth for models and LTSpice lacks some common components like `1N5221` to `1N5267` for example.

While it is true I can pick a basic model and modify it to adjust the parameters I need from the components, I fear my simulation will fall very far from the real thing. And the same happens for various ICs.

I'd like to throw a 2 for 1 question:

1. What is the best way to find LTSPice models, or working around the lack of them?
2. Is there a source for the `1N5221` to `1N5267` diodes spice models?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Look on the site of the manufacturers of those diodes. 2) the diodes you meantion are **zener diodes** 3) What are you simulating / trying to simulate that the model of a "generic" zener diode matters that much ? I dare to say that in general, any model of a zener diode with the zener voltage that you need, will be good enough for your simulation. If that is not the case and your circuit **only** works with that specific model of diode, then (in my opinion) your circuit isn't a very good design. I'd actually like to see that circuit as I think such a circuit does not exist.

Comment: LTspice is ***known*** for its lack of models, outside of those involving Linear parts. LTspice is used internally by Linear for IC design and sustained internally. It was only through a lot of effort that upper management was convinced to allow their internal design tool to become available to the "outside world" at no charge. But one of the conditions was that there was no added in-house effort made to support their competition and that effort was made so that none of their own FAB design models were allowed to "leak out." The result is a tool that lacks a lot of commonly desired models.

Comment: "I fear my simulation will fall very far from the real thing." Rest assured -- it will.  You have to know what you're looking for from a simulation, and you have to know *how* it's going to miss "the real thing".

Comment: You can find an LTspice user group on the web (search for it.) In their files, they have worked together to create a lot of useful models. So that's one place to start. I also have my own set cobbled from ORCAD model, taken in a snapshot a few decades ago, and this include a great many older models of BJTs, JFETs and MOSFETs. The more modern ones can often be found at the manufacturer's own web site. If not, contact a local FAE and just ask them for help. That said, you should work from the datasheet where possible. Some models do require a lot of work, though, so ask in those cases.

Comment: I'd like to echo @TimWescott 's comment with more deets. Effectively using SPICE requires some underlying knowledge of what's going on within the model and not blindly trusting it. I got into a little spat the other day in some comments warning that the 1N5817 model built into LTspice doesn't model reverse breakdown at all. I had to post dc sweep simulation snips showing this behavior. You need to be aware of quirks like this. Only some manufacturers will put comments in the .LIB file telling you what's modeled.

Comment: @SteKulov I think the 1N5817 is a rectifier diode. It's well-known that many diode Spice models don't include BV and IBV parameters. They have to be added, if you want that behavior. Some manufacturers include them in their models, some don't. But pretty much all zener diodes will likely have them (for obvious reasons.) I operate on the assumption that if it is a zener, they are included and if it is not a zener then odds are that they aren't present. (I assume the behavior isn't modeled, unless the diode is intended for zener purposes.)

Comment: @jonk That's exactly my point. You of course know this, but the LTspice UI will tell an unseasoned user that the 1N5817 has a breakdown voltage of 20V because it parses the `Vpk=20` parameter. That parameter is for informational purposes only and doesn't affect the model. The answer that was eventually accepted for the particular question I'm referencing assumed that faulty premise.

Comment: @SteKulov LTspice isn't, and never was, intended for unseasoned users. It was placed into public access after much gnashing of teeth. Even then, only on the basis that no substantial costs went beyond their internal and marketing support needs. Even the help file is overly terse and barely enough for those who mostly don't need help. There's marketing value to the tool. But really only to people who are pretty well informed about spice. Unseasoned users can either attend a marketing seminar or go find outside support, so far as Linear cares.

Comment: @jonk Couldn't have said it better myself.